# Monitoring/Warning for IOWait

Tags: linux, iowait

I had a downtime today on my server because of a high IOWait. I could not do mostly anything on the server, I managed only to run `top` to see the IOWait, but I did not have `iotop` installed at that time, so I couldn't see which process is causing it. Is there anyway to monitor the iowait live and in case of high load to dump information about the process which is causing it?

Answer (score 1):

I would take the approach of understanding *why* you have I/O wait. It's probably not a process you'd want to kill indiscriminately, but a result of your system configuration and resources.

Do you have enough storage resources? Is your server physical or virtual? Does your application write a lot of data? These are all factors that could impact the I/O wait levels and performance.

When you were able to check `top`, did you see a high system load as well? If so, you may want to alert on that. A simple way to check and notify for such conditions is to use a system monitor like **[Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/)**.

Comment: I don't want necesarilly to kill the process. I only want to know which one causes it when it happens to be able to prevent it. At this moment I have no idea which process was causing the IOWait. System load was around 1%.